# cant display values of array

Tags: angularjs, node.js, html

I have a textbox which display the code of users

```
<label class="control-label">USER CODE:</label>
<input placeholder="Enter a User Code" type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="user.userCode"/>
```

On a show button it calls an api which fetches the product code assigned to particular user.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info"><i class="fa fa-hand-o-up" ng-click="getAssignedProducts(user.userCode)"></i>Show</button>
```

The product code is displayed in the table:-

```
<label style="text-align:center;">Mapped Products:</label>
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="margin:auto;">
  <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Product Code</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="row in assignedProduct track by $index">
        <td>{{row}}{{$last ? '' : ', '}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

My api code is:-

```
function getAssignedProducts(userCode) {
    return $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: '/api/user/assignedProduct?userCode=' + userCode
    });
}
```

My directive code:-

```
scope.getAssignedProduct = function(userCode) {
    ApiServices.getAssignedProduct(userCode).then(
        function(response) {
            scope.assignedProduct = response.data;
        },
        function(err) {
            // Handle error here
            console.log('Error' + JSON.stringify(err.data));
        });
}
```

Here, assignedProduct is an array in backend which stores string values.

What my issue is, the api is calling correctly but the data is not displaying in table.I think I am not displaying data correctly in directive. Can anyone tell me where is my mistake.

Comment: Your API call is written in the directive controller? If yes, then if your table is written in templateUrl specified in a directive? If not, then it won't display the result. Please add the declaration of controller/directive and the file name to get the accurate answer.

Comment: my api call is in directive and the table is written in templateUrl specified in directive.But still data is not appearing

Comment: Please log the data in browser console as you are saying back-end is returning data correctly and view has a problem. That will tell you where exactly the problem is. If the response has data then, next step after that would be just print {{ assignedProduct | json }} in your template HTML. This is simple troubleshoot which I do in such case. Also see if a browser is complaining anything?

Comment: I tried your solution @Nehal Soni and it worked. Actually I am facing new problem here which is api is not hitting on clicking the show button.What's the error there?

Comment: Again your show button has to be in directive template as your API is getting called from directive. If it is proper, then make a fiddle/plunker or else post more code to get the accurate answer. You can always make a prototype in editor and add static json repsonse to replicate the behaviour.